# What's the best way to use 'super' in a new context?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

When using classes in ES6, the 'super' keyword can only be used directly within class methods.  Which is perfectly reasonable, but sometimes awkward.

This is the work-around that I've come up with, but is there a better way?

```js
class foo {

  constructor () {
  }

  bar (x) {
    console.log('bar x:', x);
  }

}

class morefoo extends foo {

  constructor () {
    super();
  }
 
  bar (x) {
    let super_bar = super.bar.bind(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
      //super.bar(x*2); // => 'super' keyword unexpected here
      super_bar(x*2);
    }, 0); 
  }

}

let f = new morefoo;
f.bar(33);
```

Comment: since `morefoo` is a child of `foo`, you should be able to just do `this.bar(x*2)`

Comment: @ps2goat: The child overwrites `bar`.

Comment: eh, missed that part. what's the use case for this?

Comment: @ps2goat The use case is that bar() in the subclass does extra things as well as what bar() in the main class does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you want to reference `super` inside a callback:

```js
class foo {

  constructor () {
  }

  bar (x) {
    console.log('bar x:', x);
  }

}

class morefoo extends foo {

  constructor () {
    super();
  }
 
  bar (x) {
    setTimeout(() => super.bar(x*2), 0); 
  }

}

let f = new morefoo;
f.bar(33);
```

Arrow functions treat certain keywords/variables differently (`this`, `arguments`, `super`).

Comment: Thank you -- I keep forgetting about arrow functions.  But I'll add an answer with a supplementary question.

Comment: I was going to ask about a slightly more complicated example using a promise instead of just setTimeout, but then I realised that arrow functions work with the `.then` clause of promises too.  So your answer works perfectly.